# Definitions of Semisimple Lie Algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

We usually define semisimplicity of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}\subset M_n ({\bf R})$ 
 from two ways. I want to know the relation between them.

One of the definitions of semisimple Lie algebra is as follows (cf 156 page of the book : Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces - Helgason):

A Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}\subset M_n ({\bf R})$ is semisimple if

(1) whenever $\mathfrak{g}$ on ${\bf R}^n$ has an invariant subspace $W$, then $W$ has a complementary invariant subspace.

(2) $\{ v\in {\bf R}^n| Xv=0$ for all $X\in \mathfrak{g}\}=\{0\}$.

Here I have a question : Semisimplicity of $\mathfrak{g}\subset M_n ({\bf R})$ is equivalent to the following :

Invariant subspace of ${\bf ad}(\mathfrak{g})$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ has complementary subspace which is invariant.

The above statement is true ? If it is true then how can we prove ?

Thank you in advance.

[Additional Question]-------------------------------------------------------

Assume that $\{ v\in {\bf R}^n|\ Xv=0$ for all $X\in \mathfrak{g} \} = \{ 0
\}$. Then a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} \subseteq \{ X\in M_n({\bf R}) |\ X=-X^T \}$ is semisimple on ${\bf R}^n$, that is, invariant subspace has a complementary invariant subspace. This statement is correct ? If it is right how can we prove ?

Comment: I am unsure of how to understand (1). What do you mean by its complementary? A subspace does not usually have a uniquely determined complement.

Comment: I mean as follows : If $V$ has a basis $\{ e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and if $W$ is spanned by $\{ e_i\}_{i=1}^k$ then its complementary subspace is a subspace spanned by $\{e_i\}_{i=k+1}^n$.